# Python deep learning with theano the basic program of mnist

Tags: python, pycharm, theano, conda, mnist

I am a newbie to the deep learning, and I am just doing my baby steps in it. I have a MacBook Pro 2017 model, and I am trying to run the *MNIST dataset* with *Logistic Regression*. When I run the sample code which is mentioned in the official deep learning website, I am receiving the following error..

```
<i>Downloading data from http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/deep/data/mnist/mnist.pkl.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/abi/PycharmProjects/LogisticRgr_test/logist_test.py", line 475, in <module>
sgd_optimization_mnist()
File "/Users/abi/PycharmProjects/LogisticRgr_test/logist_test.py", line 277, in sgd_optimization_mnist
datasets = load_data(dataset)
File "/Users/abi/PycharmProjects/LogisticRgr_test/logist_test.py", line 205, in load_data
urllib.request.urlretrieve(origin, dataset)
File "/Users/abi/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
File "/Users/abi/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 249, in retrieve
tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/abi/PycharmProjects/LogisticRgr_test/../data/mnist.pkl.gz'

Process finished with exit code 1</i>
```

Comment: At a guess (don't know quite what you're trying), it's trying to open a local file it can't find - try investigating why that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in file logistic_sgd.py http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/logistic_sgd.py

first you can download this file manually on http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/deep/data/mnist/mnist.pkl.gz
an add file 'mnist.pkl.gz' to your current Directory, because the function checks first, if the mnist file is in the data Directory. If you do this, so check if installed numpy and everything works fine.

```
def load_data(dataset):
''' Loads the dataset

:type dataset: string
:param dataset: the path to the dataset (here MNIST)
'''

#############
# LOAD DATA #
#############

# Download the MNIST dataset if it is not present
data_dir, data_file = os.path.split(dataset)
if data_dir == "" and not os.path.isfile(dataset):
    # Check if dataset is in the data directory.
    new_path = os.path.join(
        os.path.split(__file__)[0],
        "..",
        "data",
        dataset
    )
    if os.path.isfile(new_path) or data_file == 'mnist.pkl.gz':
        dataset = new_path

if (not os.path.isfile(dataset)) and data_file == 'mnist.pkl.gz':
    from six.moves import urllib
    origin = (
        'http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/deep/data/mnist/mnist.pkl.gz'
    )
    print('Downloading data from %s' % origin)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(origin, dataset)

print('... loading data')

# Load the dataset
with gzip.open(dataset, 'rb') as f:
    try:
        train_set, valid_set, test_set = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
    except:
        train_set, valid_set, test_set = pickle.load(f)
# train_set, valid_set, test_set format: tuple(input, target)
# input is a numpy.ndarray of 2 dimensions (a matrix)
# where each row corresponds to an example. target is a
# numpy.ndarray of 1 dimension (vector) that has the same length as
# the number of rows in the input. It should give the target
# to the example with the same index in the input.
```

2. the line with 
   `urllib.request.urlretrieve(origin, dataset)` did not work for me either, but you just have to download the file so i did some changes

---

```
from urllib import request

def get(url):
    with request.urlopen(url) as r:
       return r.read()

def download(url, file=None):
    if not file:
        file = url.split('/')[-1]
    with open(file, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(get(url))
```

and call the download function

```
url = "http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/deep/data/mnist/mnist.pkl.gz"
download(url)
```

After these changes, the function **load_data** works fine for me

---

---

I did some more Investigation:

Replace this statement:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(origin, dataset)
```

with the following Statement:

```
dataset, header = urllib.request.urlretrieve(origin, 'mnist.pkl.gz')
```

you get a tuple back from urlretrieve and with dataset from the tuple you have to work with in the gzip.open statement!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I have manually downloaded the file and it worked perfectly. Along with that for the MacOs I was asked to download and install Xcode and gcc which was as an automatic prompt and I just clicked okay and install before running the code. I was also wondering why it was automatically downloaded.